# java access time to variables

Tags: java, compiler-optimization

Suppose we have a class `Const.java` containing 1000 String constants:

```
public static final String foo1 = "foo1";
public static final String foo2 = "foo2";
...
public static final String foo1000 = "foo1000";
```

Now, some method in another class executes

```
String s = Const.foo1000;
```

Does access time of variables depend on the number of such variables?
(That is, if there were 1,000,000 Strings in `Const.java`, would code run at the same speed?)

Comment: It is impossible to declare 1,000,000 string constants in `Const.java`. The technical maximum is less than 33,000. But the impact on the performance is exactly zero, as [explained by VGR](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44504273/2711488); if the class `Const` only contains these declarations, it will not even get loaded at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The access time will be always the same.

Your class is loaded using the the classloader into RAM memory when the application starts. Constants (static/final) are stored in a memory position that is replaced in your code at compile time wherever it's used.

The only difference that you should notice is at the start time of your application, that will be proportional to the amount of variables that you have in the class.

Accessing a memory position is always O(1), like retrieving an object from a HashMap.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it would run at the same speed.  An important reason is that the constants are all resolved at compile time, not at run time.

Any static final field consisting only of literals, or values of other static final fields which consist only of literals, is analyzed when the code is compiled.  In fact, if you were to decompile the assigment, you would see:

```
String s = "foo1000";   // No reference whatsoever to Const
```

Comment: This applies to all `final` variables with a constant initializer, there is no requirement to be a `static` field.